# getting @Configurable working

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, gradle, aop

I am working with intellij, Spring and Gradle.

I have a class that sends E-Mails. Said class is created using the new operator. Now i [read](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable), that the @Configureable annotation can be used to autowire such a class. I cant seem to make it work though. Maybe someone has expirience with this and can point me into the right direction?

```
    @Service
    @EnableAsync
    @Configurable(dependencyCheck=true,autowire= Autowire.BY_TYPE)
    public class EmailCommand implements ICommand {

    /**
     * standard logger.
     */
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    /**
     * {@link MailSender} capable of sending out mails.
     */
    @Autowired
    @Inject
    private MailSender mailSender;

    /**
     * Sring with the Mailcontent.
     * Taken from application.properties
     */
    @Value("${spring.mail.content}")
    private String mailContent;

    /**
     * Sring with the mailsubject.
     * Taken from application.properties
     */
    @Value("${spring.mail.subject}")
    private String mailSubject;

    /**
     * The name of the sensor which triggered the alert.
     */
    private String sensorName;

    /**
     * the email-address to send the mail to.
     */
    private String emailAddress;

    /**
     * Standard constructor only used by Spring FW.
     */
    public EmailCommand() {
    }


    /**
     * Constructor used by the application.
     *
     * @param sensorName   {@link EmailCommand#sensorName}
     * @param emailAddress {@link EmailCommand#emailAddress}
     */
    public EmailCommand(final String sensorName, final String emailAddress) {
        this.sensorName = sensorName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        String content = "asdf";//mailContent.replace("%SENSORNAME%", sensorName);
        message.setText(content);
        message.setSubject("asdf");
        message.setTo(emailAddress);
        try {
            mailSender.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info("Sending Mail");
    }
}
```

I am creating that class using the new operator:

```
return new EmailCommand(title, user.getEmail());
```

after that i get a NPE on:

```
mailSender.send(message);
```

Since the mailsender is empty.

My Application is annotated like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude =
            {org
                    .springframework
                    .boot
                    .autoconfigure
                    .security
                    .SecurityAutoConfiguration.class
            })
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = 
EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

The WebApplication class is in the Top-Level-Package and all other classes are in subpackages of that class.

My Gradle-File:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-
plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://maven.springframework.org/release' }
    maven { url 'http://maven.springframework.org/milestone' }
    maven { url 'http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'http://download.java.net/maven/2' }
 }

war {
    baseName = 'noisemap'
    from '../noisemap-frontend/build'
}

test {
    ignoreFailures = true;
}

configurations {
    aspect
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '6.7'
    ignoreFailures = true
}

dependencies {
//GMail
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v1-rev132-1.22.0'
compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.5.5'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev65-1.22.0'

aspect 'org.springframework:spring-instrument:3.0.4.RELEASE'
compile configurations.aspect.dependencies

compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.39'
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-config:1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-web:1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
compile 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.1.0.RELEASE'
runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
runtime('com.h2database:h2')
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')
testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19')
testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
testCompile('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0')
}

bootRun {
    environment SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: environment.SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE ?: "development"
    jvmArgs = ["-javaagent:"+configurations.aspect.asPath]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mauravan You are right about creating a bean and use it with autowire.

But you could there is many ways to create beans in the Spring.

1st: in spring you inject object in a class using Autowire and not Inject that is used i CDI.

```
/**
 * {@link MailSender} capable of sending out mails.
 */
@Autowired
private MailSender mailSender;
```

2nd: You can create your bean using @Service or @Component annotation and inject it in the class that send the email unless

```
return new EmailCommand(title, user.getEmail());
```

3rd: After all you will have it

```
@Service
class EmailCommand {
    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;

    @Async
    public void send(SimpleMailMessage message) {
        this.mailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

It's just a example...

Comment: Hi bpedroso, Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if i get what you are saying. The class per se is working and i am able to instantiate it. The problem is, that the spring context doesn't seem to pick the class up and autowire the properties. When i autowire the class manually via autowirecapablebeanfactory everything works fine. I am just trying to get rid of the factory.